# Find the hidden Infinite Loop

Tags: c++

I'm working on [this problem](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=82) and my solution seems to work for every case I can imagine to try, and do so in well under the 3 second time limit, but when I submit online it still exceeds 3 seconds. I think there must be a case that causes this while loop to go on indefinitely:

```
while (!equals(availableChars, testChars)){
        next = getNextAlphaString(high, next, availableChars, it);      
        fillCharSet(next, testChars);       
    }
```

but I've tested my functions a bunch and I can't figure out what it is...hoping you guys might see something.  Here are the helper functions:

```
bool equals(multiset<char>& availableChars, multiset<char>& test){  
    multiset<char>::iterator it;
    for (it = availableChars.begin(); it != availableChars.end(); it++){
        if ((int)availableChars.count(*it) != (int)test.count(*it)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

*

```
string getNextAlphaString(char& high, string next, multiset<char>& availableChars, multiset<char>::iterator& it){   
for (int i=next.size()-1; i>=0; i--){

    if (next[i] != high){
        it = availableChars.find(next[i]); 
        while(*it == next[i]){
            it++;           
            if (it == availableChars.end()){it = availableChars.begin(); break;}
        }
        next[i] = *it;
        break;}
    else{
        it = availableChars.begin();
        next[i] = *it;
    }       
}
return next;
}
```

*

```
void fillCharSet(string in, multiset<char>& chars){
    chars.clear();
    for (int i=0; i<in.size(); i++){chars.insert(in[i]);}
}
```

Comment: I'm going to guess you can't use `std::next_permutation`?

Comment: Get a real compiler / debugger pair and try to find for yourself?

Comment: @chris: took me a moment to realize you weren't the same chris.

Comment: I'm not posisitve, but this algorithm looks quite slow. I'm quite sure this can be written in a completely different way to be much faster.

Comment: Adding onto Mooing Duck, seeing as how `std::next_permutation` is a template function, you could take a look at the implementation to get some ideas.

Comment: The line like this is a source of error `for (int i=next.size()-1; i>=0; i--){`. What if the string is empty... `i ` would be negative and keep the loop running forever

Comment: @Aditya : If the string is empty, `i` will be initialized to `-1` and `i>=0` will prevent the loop body from executing at all.

Comment: oh! my bad.. i wrongly saw >= as !=.

Comment: @Mooring Duck and chris: I'm sure there are faster algorithms, but this has been my best attempt so far.  I'm writing this code more for educational rather than usage purposes (trying to get a better grip on problem solving).  But I will take a look at     std::next_permutation...I'd never heard of it. Are you guys thinking it may not be an infinite loop at all, but rather just be too slow?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well...here I go answering my own question.  I rewrote it with next_permutation, and it was massively easier and more efficient.  I still haven't solved the actual looping problem with the other solution, but now I don't need to.  Thanks everyone for the tips :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article to detect infinite loops using GDB:

http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbinfloop.html

Hopefully this will help you with the problem.

Comment: For a second I thought you were proposing that someone had solved the halting problem :D